# Error "out of range" insertando una tabla

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

import sqlite3

class Product:

    db_name = 'database_escuela.db'

    def __init__(self, window):
        # Se crea una ventana
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title('Aplicacion Escuela Ministerio Teocratico')

        # Crear un Frame o contendor
        frame = LabelFrame(self.wind, text = 'Registro de Estudiantes de la Escuela Ministerio       
        Teocratico')
        frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 10, pady = 20, padx = 20)

        # Tabla
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(height = 10, columns = 3)
        self.tree.grid(row =0, column = 0, columnspan = 5)

        self.tree.heading('#0', text = '1er Nombre', anchor = CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('#1', text = '2do Nombre', anchor = CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('#2', text = '1er Apellido', anchor = CENTER)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = Tk()
    application = Product(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Me aparece este error:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "prueba10.py", line 30, in <module>
>     application = Product(window)
>   File "prueba10.py", line 25, in __init__
>     self.tree.heading('#2', text = '1er Apellido', anchor = CENTER)
>   File "C:\Users\Juan Carlos Pantoja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\ttk.py",line 1303, in heading
>     return _val_or_dict(self.tk, kw, self._w, 'heading', column)
>   File "C:\Users\Juan Carlos Pantoja\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter\ttk.py",line 297, in _val_or_dict
>     res = tk.call(*(args + options))
> _tkinter.TclError: Column #2 out of range
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eso pasa por como indicas las columnas. La manera correcta sería asignándole al parámetro column una tupla/lista con un elemento por cada columna.

```
self.tree = ttk.Treeview(height = 10, columns = ('#1','#2','#3'))
```

ttk.Treeview incluye un columna por defecto #0 que usualmente es usada para identificar las filas. Para ocultarla puedes establecer la propiedad show del tree igual a headings

```
self.tree['show'] = 'headings'
self.tree.heading('#1', text = '1er Nombre',  anchor = CENTER) 
self.tree.heading('#2', text = '2do Nombre', anchor = CENTER)
self.tree.heading('#3', text = '1er Apellido', anchor = CENTER)
```

Comment: Excelente respuesta, ya lo corregí y me funciono, muchísimas gracias por l ayuda brindada.

Answer (score 1):

El argumento `columns` del inicializador de la clase `ttk.Treeview` no sirve para indicar el número de columnas que quieres que tenga el `TreeView` como creo que esperas.

Lo que se espera que le pases a `columns` es **una secuencia de cadenas con identificadores para cada columna**. Los identificadores pasados serán usados internamente para identificar las columnas. La primera columna, la de los iconos, tiene siempre `'# 0'` como identificador, las que agregues mediante `columns` se agregarán a ésta primera columna.

Cuando haces `columns=3`, lo que haces es agregar una única columna aparte de `"#0"` con `"3"` como identificador, debería quizás dar una excepción al pasar un entero en mi opinión, pero no lo hace...

Como solo tienes dos columnas, cuando intestas agregar la cabecera para la tercera tienes el error que te muestra, porque no existe la tercera columna.

La solución es pasar una lista o tupla con dos cadenas a modo de identificadores, una menos que el número de columnas que deseas ya que la primera siempre es '# 0':

```
import sqlite3
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


class Product:

    db_name = 'database_escuela.db'

    def __init__(self, window):
        # Se crea una ventana
        self.wind = window
        self.wind.title('Aplicacion Escuela Ministerio Teocratico')

        # Crear un Frame o contendor
        frame = tk.LabelFrame(
            self.wind,
            text='Registro de Estudiantes de la Escuela Ministerio Teocratico'
            )
        frame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=10, pady=20, padx=20)

        # Tabla
        self.tree = ttk.Treeview(height=10, columns=("#1", "#2"))
        self.tree.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=5)

        self.tree.heading('#0', text='1er Nombre', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('#1', text='2do Nombre', anchor=tk.CENTER)
        self.tree.heading('#2', text='1er Apellido', anchor=tk.CENTER)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = tk.Tk()
    application = Product(window)
    window.mainloop()
```

Te aconsejo que evites usar wildcard para importar (`from módulo import *`), es una mala práctica generalmente.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, seguiré su consejo,